# C#: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I am trying to do the following:

```
where wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm >= dueDate.Year - 3 && wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm >= 2006 
    && wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm < timeframe
```

and get the above error message.  Then I tried this:

```
where (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year >= dueDate.Year - 3) 
    && (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ??  new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year >= 2006) 
    && (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ??  new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year < timeframe)
```

but I get an "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'bool'" error.

How can I perform the operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>=` operator binds more tightly than the `??` operator. Which means that you're implicitly doing this comparison:

```
where (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? (new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year >= dueDate.Year - 3)) 
   && (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? (new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year >= 2006)) 
   && (wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? (new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year < timeframe))
```

in which the left side of the `??` is a DateTime and the right side is a boolean (returned by the comparisons); this matches the error message you're now getting.

You actually want this behavior:

```
where ((wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year) >= dueDate.Year - 3) 
   && ((wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year) >= 2006) 
   && ((wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm ?? new DateTime(3000,1,1).Year) < timeframe)
```

Add the parentheses as in the lower example.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me why what I was doing would not work.

Comment: Note that there's still an issue with your datatypes. Might be better to save off the year (or 3000, if the DateTime is null) in its own variable and use that for comparisons. Your code will be clearer and you won't have to make a lot of new DateTime objects you don't really use.

Answer (score 7):

`&& wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm >= 2006`

As the message clearly states, you cannot compare a date to a number.

You may want `.Year`.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie "cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int'"  DateTime is a date and int is a number.  So, yes, it's pretty clear.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: Which part of the error don't you understand? If you want to accomplish anything, you need to learn how to read error message.  (and warnings)

Answer (score 3):

`dueDate.Year - 3` returns an integer of just the year.  You can't compare an integer to a DateTime.  You would need to do something like this:

```
where wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm >= dueDate.AddYears(-3)
```

Comment: you mean where wt.Rqstcmpldt_dttm >= dueDate.AddYears(-3).Year

Comment: @SteveDog Thank you for explaining to me what I was doing wrong.